# Automation Monitoring

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation, automationstudio

I had a question about how folks monitor their automations' successes and failures. We currently have a very manual process that I'm hoping to automate (no pun intended).

Currently we:

- Receive email alerts for each automation
- Use an Excel file that list the day's expected sends to manually track each day's expected send
- If an error, we log it in the excel file and investigate

I was wondering if any folks had a way of doing this that isn't so time-consuming and manual. We have considered just having Error email alerts sent to us, but the risk is that an automation might stop in error and we would have no way of knowing it isn’t going out.

Comment: Can you give a bit more insight into what exactly you are looking to track? Are you tracking the emails sent, jobs completed or the status of each automation (regardless if there are any email activities in it)?  Would this also include Journeys?

Comment: Thanks, we are tracking the status of each automation (query + email sent). We aren't using Journeys as of yet.

Comment: If you have developer resources, you can build something via SOAP API (in 3rd party server or via SSJS script activities) to track this, but it is fairly complex.  The other option is as @Maneesh said and engage SFMC to build a custom report - but be aware, these can be costly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is not out of the box way to perform the monitoring of Automation Programs. Some workarounds can be put together but not sure if any of those will be complete in itself -

- In your Automation Program, use some email activities at different points which may help you track the progress
- Request Salesforce to build a customized report which you can schedule

Comment: Thanks! I will engage them to see if they can build a customized report.